# Race condition when using List with async-loaded rows and laid out with GeometryReader

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

This is a follow-up question from [Content hugging priority behaviour in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62800676/content-hugging-priority-behaviour-in-swiftui).

I have a List with async-loaded images for each row, which has its height set using a GeometryReader. Full code [here](https://github.com/sirghi/async-geometryreader-swiftui):

```swift
struct CountryCell: View {
    let country: Country

    @State var childSize: CGSize = .init(width: 0, height: 50)

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            AsyncImage(url: Endpoints.flag(countryCode: country.flagCode).url, placeholder: Image("flag"))
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: DeviceMetrics.size.width * 0.25, height: self.childSize.height)
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text("Country: ").bold() + Text(self.country.name)
                Text("Capital: ").bold() + Text(self.country.capital)
                Text("Currency: ").bold() + Text(self.country.currency)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background(
                GeometryReader { proxy -> AnyView in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.childSize = proxy.size
                    }
                    return AnyView(Color.clear)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Run it, the images won't replace the placeholder (maybe 1 in 10 will randomly show up), although the network requests are made. I can't figure it out, but have a hunch it's a race condition during triggering layout by the GeometryReader and the AsyncImage. If you replace:

```
.frame(width: DeviceMetrics.size.width * 0.25, height: self.childSize.height)
```

with:

```
.frame(width: DeviceMetrics.size.width * 0.25)
```

then the images will show up correctly. Similarly, if you comment out the GeometryReader, things will start to work too.

Any hints would be much appreciated.