# Translucent button like native buttons?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to mimic the native notification action buttons. I not referring to the blurred background behind the notification, but the greyish button background that's translucent:

[image]

However, I'm having trouble getting this right and ended up with this:
[image]

This is what I'm trying:

```
Button("Open Settings") {}
    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    .padding()
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.8).blur(radius: 3.0))
    .foregroundColor(.black)
    .cornerRadius(10)
```

How can I get the blurred translucent background and also get the sharp edges?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65595112/12299030?

Comment: Yes it does, thx! Too bad I have to use `UIViewRepresentable` but gets the job done until SwiftUI covers this.