# SwiftUI DatePicker -- Allow no date at all?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, datepicker

I'm working on my first SwiftUI app, and have implemented a `Form` with one of the fields being a `DatePicker`.  However, this value is completely optional.  So, it is possible that the user doesn't enter a value at all.  I'm unable to figure out, though, how I can make it so that the user doesn't need to enter the value.  The code itself is rather simple:

```
    DatePicker(selection: $expirationDate,
               displayedComponents: .date) {
        Text("Expiration")
    }
```

Is there a way so that I can indicate that `$expirationDate` can have a `Date` or can be nil?  The `DatePicker` by default seems to set the value to the current `Date` and I couldn't figure out a way to override that behavior.  Thoughts?

Comment: Barring there not being a native solution with only the picker (which I don't think there is), I'd probably make a secondary control with a toggle titled something like "Expires" (based on your variable name) that enables/shows the date control.

Comment: Have a same problem, @Shadowman have you found any workaround?

Answer (score 5):

My solution is similar to bdan's solution, but in his solution, once you set the date, you cannot remove it.

**Date not set:**
[image]

**Date set (with option to remove it):**
[image]

This is the code:

```
struct DatePickerOptional: View {

let label: String
let prompt: String
let range: PartialRangeThrough<Date>
@Binding var date: Date?
@State private var hidenDate: Date = Date()
@State private var showDate: Bool = false

init(_ label: String, prompt: String, in range: PartialRangeThrough<Date>, selection: Binding<Date?>) {
    self.label = label
    self.prompt = prompt
    self.range = range
    self._date = selection
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        HStack {
            Text(label)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            Spacer()
            if showDate {
                Button {
                    showDate = false
                    date = nil
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                        .tint(.textPrimary)
                }
                DatePicker(
                    label,
                    selection: $hidenDate,
                    in: range,
                    displayedComponents: .date
                )
                .labelsHidden()
                .onChange(of: hidenDate) { newDate in
                    date = newDate
                }

            } else {
                Button {
                    showDate = true
                    date = hidenDate
                } label: {
                    Text(prompt)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .foregroundColor(.textPrimary)
                }
                .frame(width: 120, height: 34)
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .fill(Color.customPickerBackground)
                )
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this works great, thank you @JPetric

Comment: How do you use DatePickerOptional, sending a date that is not nil, where the DatePicker shows the date correctly filled in?  I'd like the user to be able to null it out, which works fine as is.

Comment: The problem here is you have to click twice to actually open the picker

Answer (score 4):

You can add Text on top of the DatePicker that does not receive touch events, then add a white background with a prompt. This will allow the date to still be clickable.

```
struct DatePickerNullable: View {
    
    let label:String
    @Binding var date:Date?
    @State private var hidenDate:Date = Date()
    
    init(_ label:String, selection:Binding<Date?>){
        self.label = label
        self._date = selection
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ proxy in
            ZStack{
                DatePicker(label, selection: $hidenDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                if date == nil{
                    Text(label)
                        .italic()
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(width: proxy.size.width - CGFloat(label.count * 8), alignment: .trailing)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                        .allowsHitTesting(false)
                }
            }.onChange(of: hidenDate, perform: { _ in
                self.date = hidenDate
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[Default state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLZXk.png)

[Clicked state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XE7J.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's currently impossible to use `DatePicker` with an optional date. [What @jnpdx suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696263/swiftui-datepicker-allow-no-date-at-all#comment117900856_66696263) is the pattern Apple uses in Reminders, but if that's not appropriate for your use case, here's a refinement of the previous two answers that uses system stylings and eliminates all magical numbers except the corner radius.

**Tested on iOS 17.2**

[Example GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S13S.gif)

**NB:** Changing the opacity of a `DatePicker` to `0` makes it incapable of detecting taps, hence using the `ZStack` and `Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemGroupedBackground)` in `addDateButton` to cover `datePicker`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct OptionalDatePicker: View {
  
  let label: String
  let prompt: String
  let range: PartialRangeFrom<Date>
  @Binding var optionalDate: Date?

  @State private var requiredDate = Date()
  @State private var datePickerBounds = CGRect.zero
  private var dateExists: Bool { optionalDate != nil }
  
  private func deleteDate() {
    optionalDate = nil
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    LabeledContent {
      if dateExists { 
        deleteDateButton 
      }
      datePicker
        .overlay {
          addDateButton
        }
        .onChange(of: requiredDate) { _, newDate in
          optionalDate = newDate
        }
    } label: {
      Text(label)
    }
  }
  
  var datePicker: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      DatePicker(label, selection: $requiredDate, in: range, displayedComponents: .date)
        .labelsHidden()
        .fixedSize()
        .anchorPreference(key: BoundsPreferenceKey.self, value: .bounds) { geometry[$0] }
        .onPreferenceChange(BoundsPreferenceKey.self) { datePickerBounds = $0 }
    }
    .frame(width: datePickerBounds.width, height: datePickerBounds.height)
  }
  
  var addDateButton: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemGroupedBackground)
      Text(prompt)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .foregroundStyle(.accent)
        .background(Color(uiColor: .tertiarySystemFill), in: .rect(cornerRadius: 8))
    }
    .frame(width: datePickerBounds.width, height: datePickerBounds.height)
    .opacity(dateExists ? 0 : 1)
    .allowsHitTesting(false)
    .animation(.none, value: dateExists)
  }
  
  var deleteDateButton: some View {
    Button(action: deleteDate) {
      Image(systemName: "minus")
        .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
        .symbolVariant(.circle.fill)
        .tint(.red)
    }
  }
}
```

More on `BoundsPreferenceKey` [from @SirDeleck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69686529/23072197).

```
struct BoundsPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGRect = .zero
  static func reduce(value: inout CGRect, nextValue: () -> CGRect) {
    value = nextValue()
  }
}
```