# How do I detect when user reaches the bottom of a ScrollView?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I have a search bar on top of the screen. I need to hide when scrolling down and unhide when scrolling up, which I achieved using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68681075/how-do-i-detect-when-user-has-reached-the-bottom-of-the-scrollview/68681223#68681223).

But I found one issue with the calculation of `wholeSize` and `scrollViewSize`. It is giving different values on different scrolls. Suppose I am scrolling down and I am at position `y = 400` from origin, `scrollViewSize = 740`. Now again when I come back scrolling at this same position, `y = 400`, `scrollViewSize = 789`. The number is not exact, only for the inference.

I have already explored the answer above; the issue I'm facing is that sometimes, while on the bottom of the screen, the statement `currentOffset >= scrollViewSize.height - wholeSize.height` becomes false. My ScrollView bounces when it is on the bottom of the screen which I needed to be there. Here is a partial code snippet:

```
.background(GeometryReader {
    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self, value: -$0.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin.y)
}).onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { currentOffset in
    let offsetDifference: CGFloat = self.previousScrollOffset - currentOffset
    
    
    if ( abs(offsetDifference) > minimumOffset) {
        
        
        if currentOffset >= scrollViewSize.height - wholeSize.height {
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "currentOffset \(currentOffset)")
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "wholeSize.height \(wholeSize.height)")
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "scrollViewSize.height \(scrollViewSize.height)")
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "User has reached the bottom of the ScrollView.")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: ZIAnimation.durationPoint6)) {
                    if show ?? false {
                        show = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        if offsetDifference > 0 || self.previousScrollOffset < 0  {
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "Is scrolling up toward top.")
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: self.previousScrollOffset)
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "currentOffset \(currentOffset)")
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: offsetDifference)
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "wholeSize.height \(wholeSize.height)")
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "scrollViewSize.height \(scrollViewSize.height)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: ZIAnimation.durationPoint3)) {
                    if !(show ?? false) {
                        show = true
                    }
                }
            }
            
        } else if offsetDifference < 0 {
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "Is scrolling down toward bottom.")
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: self.previousScrollOffset)
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "currentOffset \(currentOffset)")
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: offsetDifference)
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "wholeSize.height \(wholeSize.height)")
            Utilities.DBLog(_object: "scrollViewSize.height \(scrollViewSize.height)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: ZIAnimation.durationPoint6)) {
                    if show ?? false {
                        show = false
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        self.previousScrollOffset = currentOffset
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this issue only in iOS 17 and above. In Below versions, it is working as expected.