# Get size of view in Swift if bigger than screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this method, to snapshot a view:

```
extension View {
    func snapshot(size: CGSize, colorScheme: ColorScheme) -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        let view = controller.view

        if view != nil {
            view!.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
            view!.backgroundColor = colorScheme != .dark ? Color.white.uiColor() : Color(hex: "#1b1c1e").uiColor()
        }

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

I currently have to provide the size of the view by using GeometryReader and updating the view every time.

However, it's making my app lag a little and I would prefer getting the size inside this function.

The View I'm snapshotting is inside a `ScrollView`, and sometimes it's super high, others it could be empty.

Is there anyway of getting `view.height` where the height includes all the items, regardless of the height of the device?

My current solution is to use `ChildSizeReader`:

```
struct ChildSizeReader<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var size: CGSize
    let content: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content()
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: proxy.size)
                    }
                )
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
            self.size = preferences
        }
    }
}

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGSize
    static var defaultValue: Value = .zero

    static func reduce(value _: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        _ = nextValue()
    }
}
```

Like so:

```
struct ChildSizeReaderExample: View {
    @State var textSize: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChildSizeReader(size: $textSize) {
                Text("Hello I am some arbitrary text.")
            }
            Text("My size is \(textSize.debugDescription)!")
        }
    }
}
```

[(Reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60861575/19020089)

And then I manually call `.snapshot(size: textSize)`

But I would prefer not to use ChildSizeReader and get the full height inside the `snapshot()` function.

`view.height` returns the max of the device height, so I'm not sure what else to do?

Please let me know if I'm missing something.